# Remove all chapters and corresponding titles in .txt file in python

Tags: python, text, nlp

I am working on a book in .txt format in python.

I would like to remove all chapters and corresponding titles.
All of them are introduced by means of the word, CHAPTER, as in the example below:

\n\n\n\nCHAPTER 2. I OBSERVE\n\n\n

All have four \n\n\n\n before the UPPERCASE word CHAPTER, but after the chapter title, the numbers of \ n vary. So the condition I would like to impose is:
Whenever \n\n\n\nCHAPTER is found, it deletes the text up to and including the next \ n.

\n\n\n\nCHAPTER 2. I OBSERVE\n\n\n -----> \n\n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import re

with open('book.txt', 'r') as f:
    text = ''.join(f.readlines())

text = re.sub(r'\n{4}CHAPTER.*\n+', '\n\n', text)

with open('book.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(text)
```

It matches all sequences of:

- 4 newlines (`\n{4}`)
- the text "CHAPTER"
- followed by some title text (`.*`)
- and any amount of newlines thereafter (`\n+`)

and replaces them with two newlines (`\n\n`).

Note: this code overwrites the original file with the modifications. You may want to write to a different file & keep the original for different analysis. Otherwise, you can just directly pass the data to your NLP library.